# gsap, revert animation after play

Tags: gsap

I'd like to play an animation with gsap, but after it has finished playing, I want to reset it. Like after playing that animation, reset, after it is finished. Without clicking anywhere or calculating the play time, sleeping or waiting the process. Just simply something like:

```
TweenLite.to(thing, 1, {x:'-20px'}).reset();
```

(ideally, there is no reset call in gsap.. how to acieve this?)

I can't get it to work with .seek(), .time(), .pause().
Those always interrupt the animation.

Preferable I want to use a simple TweenLite, or if it has to, a TimelineLite.
Im searching / looking for it since hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but here's a simple one:

```
TweenLite.to(thing, 1, {x:-20, onComplete:function() {
    this.pause(0); //seeks the tween (this) to 0 (playhead's starting position) and pauses immediately.
}});
```

Does that help?

Comment: ..but I get my hands dirty making a card game. I need to 'reset' after a couple of things beeing animated. I have trouble nesting another tweens on that onComplete solution.  ..it appears that the calling tween is not waiting for the tweens that are called by the onComplete:function_calling_other_tween.. a not so great working codepen trying to illustrate it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRLeLz